# Checking for Duplicates before insert statement in SQL

Tags: java, sql, database, sql-insert

I have a code like below:

```
protected String getCreateSQL() {
    return "INSERT INTO ROLE_ASSIGNMENT ( ID, ORG_ID, ROLE_ID, USER_ID, EFFECTIVE_FROM, EFFECTIVE_TO, ASSIGNMENT_TYPE ) VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? )";
}
```

I need to check whether the **ROLE_ID** is already there in the **ROLE_ASSIGNMENT** table or not before inserting data. If the **ROLE_ID** is already there in the Table, it should not insert the value.

**Is there any way of doing this without changing the Database constraints only from SQL side?**

Comment: Could you not check it like `SELECT ROLE_ID...` and then call that method if it doesn't exist?

Comment: which `rdbms` ?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "_SQL_" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a constraint in DB you will get an exception, just catch it (Probably a `ConstraintViolationException`).

If you doesn't have constraint in DB for ROLE_ID, you need to check it manually. You can do a select with a where clause : `ROLE_ID = your_role_id`. If it doesn't return a row, you can execute your insert statement.

Answer (score 0):

It is more an sql question? You can do it on 2 steps - first check if record exists (select that record) and if it doesn't exist then add it.

If you want to do it in one step and not add the database constrains you will have to write some bizzare SQL for example something like:

```
INSERT INTO ROLE_ASSIGNMENT 
SELECT 123,434,_values_go_here.... FROM ROLE_ASSIGNMENT A
LEFT OUTER JOIN ROLE_ASSIGNMENT B on B.ID=123 where B.ORG_ID is null limit 1
```

(I am not sure if it even works but you can see the idea)
Some databases allow you to do a big statement with select value into variable and some if else cases but it all makes the code hard to read and follow so better just avoid it.

Constrains are there for a reason ;) so my advise is to use them or do the check manually before the insert call.

Answer (score 0):

Use **Not Exists** and **Merge** for example. In Oracle it will looks like

```
merge into ROLE_ASSIGNMENT ra
    using dual
    on (ra.ROLE_ID=?)
    when not matched then
    insert( ID, ORG_ID, ROLE_ID, USER_ID, EFFECTIVE_FROM, EFFECTIVE_TO, ASSIGNMENT_TYPE )
     values ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? )
```

**Dual** is a special oracle table contains 1 row and 1 column.

Or use **Insert as Select**

For **Oracle**

```
 INSERT INTO ROLE_ASSIGNMENT 
    ( ID, ORG_ID, ROLE_ID, USER_ID, EFFECTIVE_FROM, EFFECTIVE_TO, ASSIGNMENT_TYPE ) 
        select ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? from dual 
  where not exists (select 1 from ROLE_ASSIGNMENT where role_id=?)
```

For **MySQL** will be similar (not sure)

```
INSERT INTO ROLE_ASSIGNMENT 
        ( ID, ORG_ID, ROLE_ID, USER_ID, EFFECTIVE_FROM, EFFECTIVE_TO, ASSIGNMENT_TYPE ) 
            select * from (select ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) as d 
      where not exists (select 1 from ROLE_ASSIGNMENT where role_id=?)
```